# How do I make a gnome window only available on some workspaces?

Tags: gnome, workspaces, debian

Disclaimer: Actually using Debian here, not Ubuntu, but I am knowledgeable enough to find the right packages, and compile my own if needed.

I am a rather heavy user of the Multiple Desktops (workspaces) feature of gnome. However, I would like to get a lot more use out of my screen space by being able to tell a window to only show on, say, workspaces 2 and 3, instead of all workspaces.

Is there an addon to gnome or a configuration I can set somewhere to allow for this behavior?

Comment: Are you using compiz?

Comment: Not currently. Does Compiz add this feature? It can be added fairly easily.

Comment: @ryan - yes - very easy via Compiz - see this Question and answer:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/6422/how-to-distribute-windows-over-virtual-desktops-in-gnome

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [devil's pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/), an app written to allow such customization on GNOME 2.

Note that if/when you move to GNOME 3, things might work very differently…